# JSR303 Validation Group inheritance

Tags: java, bean-validation

Given the following classes and interfaces

```
class A{
  @NotNull(groups=Section1.class)
  private String myString
}

interface All{}
interface Section1 extends All {}
```

When calling

A a = new A();
validator.validate(a,All.class);

I would expect that it should be invalid since myString is null and it's notNull group extends All but it does not.  Note that i'm using the Hibernate impl (4.0.2.GA) of the validator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expectations are backwards from what the specification requires.  From the [spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) (page 27 on the PDF):

> For a given interface Z, constraints marked as belonging to the group Z (i.e. where the annotation element groups contains the interface Z) or any of the super interfaces of Z (inherited groups) are considered part of the group Z.

In other words, if you validated with `Section1.class` and tagged `@NotNull` with `All.class`, the constraint would be applied.  But not the other way around.

Think of it as a set: `All` is a common set of constraints, and by extending `All`, `Section1` becomes a *superset* of `All`, not a subset.  Thus, when you validate using `All`, it applies only those specified by `All` and its super interfaces.

If you want `All` to be a superset of the constraints found in `Section1`, you need to flip the inheritance:

```
interface All extends Section1 /*, Section2, Section3...*/ {}
```

In this sense, you can say to yourself that `All` *inherits* all of the constraints of `Section1`.

This is also the reasonable implementation, as Java makes it extremely difficult to find out who extends a certain interface (after all, the class file might not even be available until it's referenced), but trivially easy to see the interfaces that a given interface extends.

Comment: +1 for that nice explanation. Only problem I have with the whole concept is that I cannot have the Default group extend my Sections. So when I want the Default group to validate everything I must add it everywhere where I use another group. At least I thought so. Just seen that you can redefine the Default group: http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence-redefiningdefaultgroup